# Strange exception from the new google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have recently came up with the following exception from one of the users that is using my application, has anyone got this sort of exception?

**Edit:** It is a **[Confirmed Bug](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5025)**.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10000000 (has extras) } in maps.z.bz@407c91c8
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:   maps.z.bz@407c91c8
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:822)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
    at maps.z.bz.onReceive(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
    ... 9 more
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: maps.z.bz@407c91c8
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:822)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
    at maps.z.bz.onReceive(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Make sure that you are on rev 5 of the "Google Play services" entry in the SDK Manager. If you are, and you are getting this crash, that is probably a bug somewhere in Maps V2, in which case I'd recommend posting an issue to the Google Maps issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: @CommonsWare I will get the latest revision, thank you.

Comment: Apparently the old lib with the new Google Play Services is not compatible. :( Problem is it brakes the apps that are already released with maps v2. I've raised an issue for this: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5025&thanks=5025&ts=1362047877

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm that have you edited your manifest file as follows:

Insert  element to include API key as a child of the

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="--- your API Key here ---"/>
```

Remember to replace value with your own API Key.

Please notice that you have to use debug API Key (refer to "Generate Debug API Key for Google Maps Android API v2 service") in your testing. And then replace with release API key (refer to "Create and Obtain API Key for Google Maps Android API v2 service") in your release APK.
    Add  and  of MAPS_RECEIVE.

```
<permission 
android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

where com.example.androidmapsv2 is my package, replace with your own package name.

Add uses-permission:

```
<uses-permission
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and optional:

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Specify uses-feature of OpenGL ES 2:

```
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>
```

**EDIT:**
Are you using any kind of reciever in your app?If yes then please check:

Then the cause of problem might be here:

```
unregisterReceiver(yourReciever);
```

If the receiver was already unregistered or was not registered, then call to unregisterReceiver throws IllegalArgumentException.
Confirm and tell me

Comment: The google maps v2 are works fine for me, some user got the crash i have posted above.