# Issue With Google Maps V2 Connectivity Issues

Tags: android, google-maps, broadcastreceiver

I have received a few crash reports and I am unsure what has cause them.

It is only in a recent update that this has started happening. This may mean that it just didn't happen before or I introduced it. The only thing to do with the network is register for a permission to check the network in the Android Manifest.

Anyway I hope you can point me in the direction. Here is the crash report.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10000000 (has extras) } in maps.z.bz@405d7d40
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: maps.z.bz@405d7d40
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:853)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
at maps.z.bz.onReceive(Unknown Source)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
... 9 more
```

Comment: I have asked the same question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116207/strange-exception-from-the-new-google-maps-v2

Seems like it is a bug, see the comments for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening if you're using the Maps V2 api with the old (revision 4) library and the new (3.0.25) version of the Google Play services.

It seems that Google broke the backward compatibility so if people upgrade their Google Play services the app released with the old library will be broken.

You have two possibilities at this point:

1. Release a new version of your app and update to the new library
2. Revert back to the old maps

I've raised a ticket and Google already acknowledged it:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5025&thanks=5025&ts=1362047877

Please star it to get a higher priority from Google.

Comment: No definite proof at this point. The only thing that I know is that we've released our app weeks ago with the new maps and we didn't get any crashes. The same day, that Google released the new version of the Play Services the crashes started to appear and started to accelerate (as probably more people upgraded). No definite proof though Google haven't commented on the issue I've raised yet.
We ended up temporarily removing the new Maps as we didn't have the time for a full acceptance test with the new lib.

Comment: This is a bit of a pain. I am hoping that updating to the new Google Maps library fixes it. I am trying to update the Google Play Services on a device to test it and see if I can recreate the issue but I am unable to so far. How do I update the Google Play Services?

Comment: Removed my previous comment as you answered it in your answer I just didn't pick up on it

Comment: Update the Google Maps app -> that will update the services. I wasn't able to reproduce it, though. Do you have a ConnectivityReceiver registered in the app somewhere (either in the Manifest or in code)?

Comment: I don't. I have just updated to the latest library and will now test to make sure original functionality is still there. Thanks for all your help and information

Comment: Let me know of what happens.

Comment: Just an update - the release with the new library worked fine.

Comment: Hmmm, that means you don't have any crashes about the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE reciever with rev5 library? I've talked with a guy from Lyft and they are using rev 5 but still see all these quite frequently.

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific. Worked fine as in not 100% fixed. We are seeing it less frequently but its still comng through occasionally. Do you know where they are with a fix for this?

Comment: Not really. They confirmed it as a real issue but they are really closed about their development - god knows why.